# How to connect azure development storage in f#?

Tags: azure, f#, azure-table-storage

At the moment I'm struggling to connect and do operation in f# against the local azure table storage (developmentstorage).

The only method I could find to connect with the storage Auth.StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey) doesn't seem to accept the developmentstorage=true string I'm using in the C# parse method.

I tried to use the corresponding account name and key (devstoreaccount1, Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==) but didn't worked.

Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Comment: I have open sourced an azure table storage client, written in F#, with some additional features over the Microsoft client. You may want to check it out.
https://lucifurestash.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudstorageaccount.developmentstorageaccount.aspx) to get a reference to a [`CloudStorageAccount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudstorageaccount.aspx) object which points to development storage account.

```
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
    let cloudTableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    let tableName = "dummy";
    let table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
    let tableCreated = table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Comment: Thanks Guarav... I'm gonna try this asap considering i can't use external libraries,

Answer (score 0):

This library may handle your requirements: http://dmohl.github.io/Fog/